# Android C2DM Registeration ID refresh

Tags: android

I am working on push notifications in android through C2DM. It is absolutely working fine at my end. I can send the push notifications to my device till the registration ID is valid at server end. If Registration ID got Expires(Google refreshes the Registration ID periodically) then my device is not getting any notifications.

I want to listen to the registration id change from Google. i have read some where that when Google refreshes the registration ID it notify to the application. I want to listen for that change so that i can forward the new registration ID to my server.

i followed this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When Google changes the registration ID you will get another REGISTERED push notification from C2DM sent to your app exactly as the first time you registered for C2DM so the code that handles the registration process just needs to take this into account.

For example...

When I receive a REGISTRATION notification from C2DM I create a new user account on my web server. The ID for this is stored in shared preferences. so before sending an HTTPOST to the web server to create a new account I check to see if I have that user id in shared preferences. If it exists I update the web server user with the new token rather than creating a new user.